# Multiple No's But One Yes SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a query where user has multiple renewals but only one of them is set to yes. I want to get a query where if all of them are no (0) to return their name.

```
SELECT u.id, CONCAT(u.fname, " ", u.lname) as full_name, renewals.renewRemind
     FROM user u 
INNER JOIN userRenewals renewals ON u.id = renewals.user_id
WHERE u.status = 1
AND renewals.renewRemind = 0
HAVING COUNT(renewals.renewRemind == 1) < 1
```

Example

```
Billy - Renewal
ID: 39 - YES
ID: 40 - NO
ID: 43 - NO
ID: 50 - NO

 Vicky - Renewal
    ID: 78 - NO
    ID: 80 - NO
    ID: 100 - NO
    ID: 119 - NO
```

Vicky should show up in query, billy not.

Comment: Show sample data.

Comment: You might be able to use a `SUM()` function instead of `COUNT()`. In other words, since you are looking for all values to be 0, the sum of those will also be 0. Another option is to query `WHERE NOT EXIST` and search for a renewal.

Comment: I don't get it. First you say you are looking for users with multiple rows but only one YES. Then you say you are looking for users with no YES. So which now? Are you looking for two different queries?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT u.id, CONCAT(u.fname, " ", u.lname) AS full_name, r.renewRemind
FROM user u INNER JOIN 
     userRenewals r 
     ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM userRenewals r1 WHERE r1.user_id = r.user_id AND r1.renewRemind = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT u.id, CONCAT(u.fname, " ", u.lname) as full_name, renewals.renewRemind
     FROM user u 
INNER JOIN userRenewals renewals ON u.id = renewals.user_id
WHERE u.status = 1
AND renewals.renewRemind = 0
AND u.id not in (
    select user_id
    from renewals
    where renewRemind=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT u.id, CONCAT(u.fname, " ", u.lname) as full_name, renewals.renewRemind
     FROM user u 
 JOIN userRenewals renewals ON u.id = renewals.user_id
WHERE u.status = 1
group by u.id
having sum(renewals.renewremind) = 0
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5cc02a/5)

EDIT 1:

Actually, this might be faster as it doesn't need a join:

```
SELECT distinct u.id, CONCAT(u.fname, " ", u.lname) as full_name FROM user u 
WHERE u.status = 1
and u.id not in (select user_id from userrenewals where renewremind=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple sum check is needed
Notice that I dropped the join condition that the renewal should be zero
You want all cases to be joined, not to filter 1 cases in advance, but only that sum to zero

```
SELECT
u.id,
CONCAT(u.fname, " ", u.lname) as full_name,
SUM (renewals.renewRemind) rsum
     FROM 
user u 
INNER JOIN userRenewals renewals ON u.id = renewals.user_id
WHERE
u.status = 1
HAVING rsum = 0
```